# Creating MySQL table with PHP foreach loop - error with syntax

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Building my own ecommerce website and within the back-end ive created a form where admins can create certain product filter groups (colours for example).

When im trying to insert the new table into the database im using a foreach loop to make sure no blank entries are inserted (and to prevent these blank entries causing issues).

However I have encountered a syntax issue and i've researched this fully without any success.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'entry_date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)' at line 1

My code:

```
// GROUP NAME PROVIDED

$group_name = $_POST['g_name'];

// FILTER OPTIONS PROVIDED

$filter_1 = $_POST['filter_1'];
$filter_2 = $_POST['filter_2'];
$filter_3 = $_POST['filter_3'];
$filter_4 = $_POST['filter_4'];
$filter_5 = $_POST['filter_5'];
$filter_6 = $_POST['filter_6'];
$filter_7 = $_POST['filter_7'];
$filter_8 = $_POST['filter_8'];
$filter_9 = $_POST['filter_9'];
$filter_10 = $_POST['filter_10'];
$filter_11 = $_POST['filter_11'];

include '../connection.php';

$query = "CREATE TABLE $group_name (
entry_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
product_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,";

$newarray = array($filter_1,$filter_2,$filter_3,$filter_4,$filter_5,$filter_6,$filter_7,$filter_8,$filter_9,$filter_10,$filter_11);

    // For each value that is not NULL
    foreach ($newarray as $key => $value) {
        if (is_null($value) === false) {
            $new_array[$key] = $value;
            echo $value;

           $query = "$value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,";

        }

    }

$query= "entry_date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

// Checking if query was successful or not

if (mysqli_query($connection, $query )) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

I've tried different variations to the timestamp insertion but had no luck.

It's worth noting that I have also split my query up so that the foreach loop can be included.

Any help would be appreciated!

**P.S I know this code is open to SQL injection, i want to get it functioning before making it secure!**

Thanks.
Stan.

**Working code:**

```
// GROUP NAME PROVIDED

$group_name = $_POST['g_name'];

// FILTER OPTIONS PROVIDED

$filter_1 = $_POST['filter_1'];
$filter_2 = $_POST['filter_2'];
$filter_3 = $_POST['filter_3'];
$filter_4 = $_POST['filter_4'];
$filter_5 = $_POST['filter_5'];
$filter_6 = $_POST['filter_6'];
$filter_7 = $_POST['filter_7'];
$filter_8 = $_POST['filter_8'];
$filter_9 = $_POST['filter_9'];
$filter_10 = $_POST['filter_10'];
$filter_11 = $_POST['filter_11'];

include '../connection.php';

$query = "CREATE TABLE $group_name (
entry_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
product_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,";

$newarray = array($filter_1,$filter_2,$filter_3,$filter_4,$filter_5,$filter_6,$filter_7,$filter_8,$filter_9,$filter_10,$filter_11);

$filtered_array = array_filter($newarray);

    // For each value that is not NULL
    foreach ($filtered_array as $key => $value) {

            $filtered_array[$key] = $value;
            echo $value;

           $query .= "$value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,";       


    }

$query .= "entry_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

echo "<br><br>".$query;

// Checking if query was successful or not

if (mysqli_query($connection, $query )) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: `$query= "entry_date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";` => `$query .= "entry_date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";` just missing a dot here and possibly inside the loop also.

Comment: Can you please print out the SQL statement (probably in your error handler)?

Comment: Ah so it appears that the for each loop isnt functioning correctly as the blank entries are still appearing: 

CREATE TABLE colours ( 
entry_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
product_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
red VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
blue VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
green VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,e
ntry_date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: I've fixed the for each loop by filtering the array first with $filtered_array = array_filter($newarray);  but im still getting a syntax issue, is it something to do with the 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' ??

Comment: Can you please update the question with the latest version of your code, and the contents of $query?

Comment: i don't see where you define what datatpye entry_date has. you just define the default

Comment: Can you share the **full generated query**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the type:

```
entry_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
entry_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: This is what was causing the issue, I updated the code and it now creates the tables. Thank you Philipp!

Answer (score 0):

you overwrite your variable $query

use =. if you want to accumulate data in a string

```
$query =. "entry_date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

buy the way it's not a really good style to store it like this